# Eliminar post.php?url= con .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano!!

**PROBLEMA**

Estoy intentando quitar de la url post.php?url= pero no lo consigo. Llevo horas intentándolo y ya no se si la forma de enviar la url no está bien o nose... No se mucho de PHP, ¡Necesito ayuda por favor! Me voy a volver loco xD

Estoy creando un blog y la url final del post es esta:

**https://www.miurl.es/blog/css/post.php?url=url-del-post/**

Me gustaría quitar post.php?url= y que quedase así:

**https://www.miurl.es/blog/css/url-del-post/**

La url la envío medíante un formulario desde la url /blog/:

```
<form action="/blog/<?php echo $post['cat'];?>/post.php?url=<?php echo $post['url'];?>" method="post">
```

He probado muchos códigos para .htaccess que he encontrado en foros para intentar quitar el **post.php?url=** pero nada me funciona.

Agradecería mucho alguien que me resuelva esto.

**SOLUCIÓN GRACIAS A @MASTERGURU**

Agradezco a Masterguru su tiempo ya que gracias a él he resuelto el problema que tenía y que yo no hubiese averiguado jamás.

Explico brevemente los cambios que hemos realizado para resolver el problema que tenía.

**1.** En el formulario por donde paso los datos para cargar la URL del post, he eliminado **post.php?url=** para luego, desde .htaccess crear una regla en la que "añade" ese fragmento para la carga. En esta url /blog/ se muestran todos los post de todas las categorías y las cargo haciendo un

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
```

Quedaría así:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <li>
       <form action="/blog/<?php echo $post['cat'];?>/<?php echo $post['url'];?>" method="post">
          //aquí paso más datos como imagen y título        
      </form>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Estos parámetros que paso por el formulario son:

```
<?php echo $post['cat'];?> //Esto cargaría la categoría del post guardada en la base de datos.

<?php echo $post['url'];?> //Y esto la url amigable del post también guardada en la base de datos.
```

**2.** Dentro de la carpeta /blog/ tengo directorios con cada categoría que quiero con sus archivos independientes para cargar solamente los post de esa categoria, es decir, dentro de /blog/ existe /blog/css/, /blog/javascript/, /blog/ux-ui/, y todas las categorías que necesite. Cada directorio tiene su index.php, list.php y post.php. El archivo list.php carga el listado de post de esa categoría y lo añado al index con un **require** y el post.php es la plantilla donde se carga la publicación.

**3.** Con este códgio en .htaccess le indica que todas las URLs dentro de **/blog/categoria/url-del-post/** tienen que cargar con la plantilla **post.php**

Al principio daba fallos y en un categoría cargaba el archivo post.php vacío pero si que cargaba bien los post. Al final Masterguru me pasó este código añadiendo la línea 2 (!/index.php$) y línea 3 (!/list.php$) y ya funcionaban bien todas las URLs.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/list\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/post\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ /blog/$1/post.php?url=$2 [L]
```

**4.** Y así quedó finalmente mi .htaccess. Las 5 primeras línes son para añadir siempre a la URL la www. (línea 1) y el https (línea 2). Y las 3 líneas siguientes son para quitar la extensión .php de la URL de algunas páginas que tengo en la web.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/list\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/post\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ /blog/$1/post.php?url=$2 [L]
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y que este ejemplo sirva de ayuda a otras personas. De nuevo, mil gracias a @masterguru!!

Comment: Tienes que agregar tu código en la pregunta.

Comment: Me salta un **ERROR 500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: Esta linea esta mal: `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ [L]`   Yo te habia dicho esta otra seguramente: `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ /blog/$1/ [L]`.  Y esta tambien esta mal: `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/index.php$ ^blog/(.*)/index.php [L]` pues deberia ser así: `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/index.php$ /blog/$1/index.php [L]`.  Prueba a ver si ahora no da error.

Comment: Perdona pero es que estuve probando y las cambié y al final las dejé mal. He probado lo que dices y sigue dando error 500  tanto /css/ como /css/url-del-post/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba quitando esto:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ /blog/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/index.php$ /blog/$1/index.php [L]
```

y poniendo esto en su lugar:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/css/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/list\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/post\.php$
```

Esas dos líneas que estamos quitando provocaban un loop infinito pues volvian a leerse de nuevo al intentar ir a esas páginas.

La línea siguiente también lo hacía de por si, pero agregando esa condición con RewriteCond antes de la regla lo conseguimos evitar y conseguimos llegar al script **post.php** correctamente, así como al `index.php`, `list.php` y `blog/css/`, etc... (deberás ir agregando a mano todas las excepciones que tengas, aunque quizás lo mejor seria ubicarlos en otra carpeta para evitar eso cada vez que necesites ejecutar un script desde esas carpetas).

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Vale, ahora ya funciona el post con su url amigable /css/url-del-post/, pero si entro en /css/ no me carga el listado del post con esa categoría. Gracias!!!

Comment: y ese listado como se ejecuta?  con un index.php?  si lo ejecutas directamente que te dice?   es decir, si intentas /blog/css/index.php?  (para no liarla intenta comentar las lineas que vienen a continuación de las dos que ahora van bien, pues intentan agregar el www y cambiarlo a https y otro cambio raro y prueba de nuevo)

Comment: Si, /css/index.php debe de cargar el listado. Dentro del index.php hay un require 'list.php' que carga la lista de posts dentro de esa categoría. Que es lo mismo que hago en /blog/index.php pero en este muestro todas las categorías.

He probado a comentar las dos líneas siguientes y hace lo mismo. Antes te he dicho que no carga /css/ pero me he dado cuenta que en realidad lo que carga es el archivo post.php vacío y no el index.php.

Poniendo /css/index.php hace igual, cargar el post.php vacío.

Parece que está haciendo un redirección a post.php.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, mira si ahora si

Comment: FUNCIONANDO!!! TE QUIERO!!!! :D He actualizado el código en mi pregunta inicial. A los últimos cambios que me pusiste ayer he tenido que añadir esta línea **RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/index.php$ /blog/$1/index.php [L]** sino no funcionaba el post pero si la categoría. En esta línea **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/css/$** he modificado /css/ por /(.*)/ para que tome cualquier categoría, sino solamente funcionaba con la categoría css. Miles de gracias por tu tiempo!!