# Blog realizado en PHP: bot Google y herramientas SEO no indexan URL y muestran la URL sin contenido

Tags: php, mysql, seo

¡Buenos días comunidad!

He realizado un blog con PHP en el cual carga en una plantilla **post.php** todas las publicaciones. Los datos de cada publicación los paso mediante un formulario **method="post"**. Tengo una administración donde creo las publicaciones y se guardan en la base de datos.

El problema es que las URLs de las publicaciones no la indexa Google, y si utilizo alguna herramienta como **Screaming Frog** para rastrear las URLs tampoco las detecta. Si paso la URL por **GTMetrix** o **SEOChecker** que hacen una captura de lo que se ve en la URL, me pinta el **post.php** vacío, sin contenido.

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que estas URLs sean detectadas tanto por Google como por las herramientas de SEO.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

> Si pongo la URL de una publicación directamente en el navegador me
> carga el contenido vacío. Tengo que pulsar la publicación desde la web
> para que me cargue la URL con los datos.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

¡Gracias de antemano!

**SOLUCIONADO**

Estaba utilizando $_POST[''] en vez de $_GET[''] dentro de la plantilla donde cargo las publicaciones. Una vez cambiado ya me carga y me reconoce bien las URLs del blog.

Comment: verifica el [robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro) crea un [sitemap](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap) y de ya que no funcionaría si las url son todas iguales

Comment: Tengo el robots.txt y el sitemap.xml. El sitemap lo creo con Screaming Frog y por eso digo que no lee las url. Cuando paso los datos por el formulario, paso la url que tiene cada post y luego desde .htaccess le indico que esa url se carga con post.php?url=.
Aquí te pongo el enlace donde me ayudaron a hacer eso desde .htaccess:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/544642/eliminar-post-phpurl-con-htaccess
¿Si yo añado manualmente las url al sitemap sería una solución?
De todas formas me gustaría que las herramientas SEO que utilizo leyesen bien la URL para hacer ajustes en cada página.

Comment: Acabo de leer que los bots de google y otros, leen la URL antes de que reciba los datos desde la base de datos y por eso muestra el contenido vacío.

Comment: el sitemap crealo con las url como se ven antes de ser transformadas a `post.php?url=lalala` onda `www.dominio.com/lalala`

Comment: al sitemap lo podes hacer dinamico tambien con un `.htaccess` que transforme `/sitemap.xml` en `/creadordesitemaps.php` aunque con escribirlo a disco cada vez que sumas un post ya estaría bien. el sitemap ademas de subirlo a buscadores lo declaras en el `robots.txt`

Comment: He probado a pasar la url con post.php?url= en Screaming Frog y la herramienta de SEO y tampoco carga el contenido. Lo de crear el sitemap dinámico lo tengo en mente pero primero quería arreglar esto.

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de una cosa. Si pongo la URL del post directamente en el navegador, me carga el contenido vacío. Si pincho en el post dentro la web si lo carga O_o

Comment: Solucionado!!! Dentro de la plantilla que carga las publicaciones post.php estaba utilizando $_POST[''] en vez de $_GET['']. He cambiado eso y ya carga bien :D